# Computations with complex numbers and trigonometric functions

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, complex-numbers

I have the following expression:

> $$\frac{(\cos x + i \sin x)-(\cos nx + i \sin nx)(\cos x + i \sin x)}{1-(\cos x + i \sin x)}$$
>   $$=\frac{\sin (\frac{nx}{2})}{\sin (\frac{x}{2})}\cos\biggl(\frac{(n + 1)x}{2}\biggr)+ i\frac{\sin (\frac{nx}{2})}{\sin(\frac{x}{2})}\sin\biggl(\frac{(n + 1)x}{2}\biggr)$$

I am not understanding how the author derives the second term of the equality. I have tried to use the definition of division, but I did not succeed: 
 ($\frac{z_1\times\overline{z_2}}{|z_2|})$. I need to separate the real and imaginary parts, but I am not seeing how the author did it.

**Question:**

How does the author derives the expression?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Write the denominator as $(1 - \cos x) - i \sin x$ and multiply the left side of the equation with $\frac{(1 - \cos x) + i \sin x}{(1 - \cos x) + i \sin x}$. In this way, you get rid of the complex denominator. Now, I would try to use the standard equalities, something like $(\cos x)^2 = 1 - (\sin x)^2$ and the double-angle formulae.

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3115468/separating-real-and-imaginary-parts-frac-cos-x-i-sin-x-cos-nx-i-sin?rq=1), too.

Comment: Can you use $e^{i\theta}=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I can use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The left side has expressions of the form $\cos\theta + i \sin\theta,$ which can be written as $e^{i\theta}$ by [Euler's formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerFormula.html):

$$e^{ix}-e^{inx}e^{ix} \over {1-e^{ix}}$$

$$={ e^{ix}(1-e^{inx}) \over {1-e^{ix}}}$$

$$={ e^{ix}e^{ {inx/2}}(e^{{-inx}/2}-e^{inx/2}) \over {e^{ix/2}(e^{-ix/2}-e^{ix/2})}}.$$

$$={{e^{ix/2}e^{inx/2}(-2i\sin{\frac {nx} 2)}}\over{-2i\sin{\frac x2}}}$$

$$=e^{i(n+1)x/2}{\frac{\sin(\frac {nx}2)}{\sin (\frac x2)}}$$

$$={\frac{\sin(\frac{nx}2)}{\sin(\frac x2)}}\biggl(\cos \biggl({\frac {(n+1)x} 2\biggr) +i\sin\biggl({\frac {(n+1)x} 2}}\biggr)\biggr)$$

That's basically it, right?

Answer (score 1):

There's a straight track to the RHS if $n$ is odd.

Writing $\,\cos x + i\sin x = e^{ix}=z$, one has for the LHS
$$e^{ix}\frac{1-e^{inx}}{1-e^{ix}}
 \:=\: z^n+z^{n-1}+\dots+z
 \:=\: z^\frac{n + 1}{2}\Big(z^\frac{n-1}{2}+z^\frac{n-3}{2}+\dots +1+\dots +
z^{-\frac{n-3}{2}}+z^{-\frac{n-1}{2}}\Big)$$
Pairing the powers of $z$ whose exponents have opposite sign yields
$$=z^\frac{n+1}{2}\Big(2\cos\tfrac{n-1}2 x+2\cos\tfrac{n-3}2 x+
\dots +2\cos\tfrac12 x +1\Big) \\
 = \Big(\cos\tfrac{n+1}2 x+i\sin\tfrac{n+1}2x\Big)\;
\frac{\sin\big(\frac{nx}2\big)}{\sin\big(\frac x2\big)}$$
by recognising the sum of cosines as the Dirichlet kernel.